# Android Multi-module app gradle build failure

Tags: android, gradle, module

I'm trying to develop an application that uses 3 separate modules as the layers for the clean app architecture: app, data, domain. In the app dependency, I added implementation project (':domain') so I could use the class from the domain module into the app module. When I first tried to build the project I had to delete some dependencies from domain module, because they were duplicated in the app module, but now when I try to build/run the application I run into a new error

Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \Project\domain\build\intermediates\symbol_list_with_package_name\debug\package-aware-r.txt
[image: The Log]

I've tried deleting the project gradle, the domain module gradlde, invalidating caches. Nothing worked.

Comment: Did you tried clean project and rebuild the project? Also while invalidating did you enable delete cache option if not please enable the three check box? Not if you enable three check box it will delete the local history

Comment: Yes I tried everything you suggested above, still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The data and domain were application type modules and by changing them to library modules my application is now running again.

You can change a module from app to library by changing: id `'com.android.application'` with: id `'com.android.library'` in the module gradle. You also need to remove applicationId line, otherwise it'll give an error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you selected the wrong template which is the first option (Phone & Tablet) when creating module.

We should choose `Android Library` when creating new modules. This way it will use `'com.android.library'` plugin instead of `'com.android.application'` plugin.

[image]